# Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str', trying to figure out how to read from excel file

Tags: python, streamlit

```
[df3 = f.parse('b_wa', skiprows=3, nrows=14, usecols='A:H')
df3['WAIT_ASSESSMENT'] = pd.to_numeric(df3['WAIT_ASSESSMENT'], errors='coerce')
df3['ROLL_WAIT_ASSESSMENT'] = pd.to_numeric(df3['ROLL_WAIT_ASSESSMENT'], errors='coerce')
df3.dropna(inplace=True)
df3_melted = df3.melt('Month', var_name='Metric', value_name='y')
df3_melted["perc_label"] = df3_melted["y"].apply(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}")
for i, row in df3_melted.iterrows():
    if i != 0 and i != len(df3) - 1 and i != len(df3) and i != len(df3_melted) - 1:
        df3_melted.at[i, "perc_label"] = ""
df_monthly = df3_melted[df3_melted["Metric"] == "WAIT_ASSESSMENT"]
df_12_month = df3_melted[df3_melted["Metric"] == "ROLL_WAIT_ASSESSMENT"]
range_ = ["#003f5c", "#ffa600"]
```

Im not sure why there's an error but im trying to read from an excel file

Comment: Was that part of a traceback error message? If so, post it.

Comment: What's the exact error? What line is it on? What's the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the error? See how to create a [mcve], and [edit] the question. I expect it's something to do with `f"{x:.2f}"`

Comment: Use `pd.read_excel()` to read an Excel file into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Did you test `f"{x:.2f}"` on its own?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.